# How to insert QPushButton into a QLabel (PyQt4)?

Tags: pyqt4, qlabel, qpushbutton

I want to add buttons into a text on pyqt4. But I don't find any solution or an example codes.

Comment: please properly explain your question, this is not enough to understand your problem.

Comment: Why not add text to buttons? :D

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this, because Qt's rich-text only supports a [limited subset of html](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html), which does not include buttons.

Probably the best compromise is to use links within the text, and connect to the label's [linkActivated](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlabel.html#linkActivated) signal. This signal sends the url of the link, so if each link is given a href "name", it will allow you to identify which one was clicked.